# Dismissing the keyboard using firstResponder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, keyboard, dismiss, first-responder

To dismiss the keyboard I use either one of the following:

```
[sender dismissFirstResponder]
[self dismissFirstResponder]
```

The problem is, I have a situation where the user selects a text field, and some other text field is the first responder with the keyboard showing. I want to dismiss the keyboard when this particular text field is selected. So neither of these will work to dismiss the keyboard.

How can I dismiss the keyboard if I don't know who is the first responder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949806/is-there-a-way-to-detect-what-uiview-is-currently-visible/1823607#1823607) for how to find the current first responder.