# Problem reading the latest value from UITextField before closing the view

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a view that I'm displaying modally to get login information from a user. I have the following setup:

- The view controller is a `UITableViewController`
- The table has three cells: username and password fields (both of type `UITextField` within `UITableViewCell`) and one simple cell as the login button.
- Values are read from `UITextField` in `textFieldDidEndEditing:`message
- The text fields are identified by different tag values.

**The problem**

My problem is that when the focus is in a `UITextField` and user touches the login button, the respective `UITextField`'s `textFieldDidEndEditing:`message is sent **after** the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. Now the issue here is that I'm sending a message of new user credentials to my `LoginViewControllerDelegate` in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and at that time the text field's value is not read yet.

**Some Ideas**

I have some ideas how to fix this, but I have complications with each of them.

First, I could close the login view and the delegate is notified during the closing, but I want to give the delegate (one who owns this login view) full control and I think it should be the delegate's job to close the login view on successful login (the login view only reads the credentials, the delegate validates these).

Second, I could also read the username or password just before calling the delegate but then I'd have to look up the text fields. If the views are not visible, I think it is wrong to assume that the cells do exist. This is just a big if, but I wan't to make it right. Would it be ok to retain the `UITextField`s? This way, however, I can't use some custom cell that would itself provide the textfield.

Basically I want the following:

1. Need for (valid) user credentials is detected, login view is popped up
2. User inputs the username and password and invokes done.
3. The delegate validates these credentials. If they do not work, a message is shown and try step 2 again.
4. Credentials are ok, so close the login view and continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all tricks I finally figured that simply resigning the first responder right before invoking the delegate fixed this. In the table view controller I simply had to add a call:

```
    [[self.view findFirstResonder] resignFirstResponder];
```

The `findFirstResonder` is from a category and can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949806/is-there-a-way-to-detect-what-uiview-is-currently-visible).

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of using third cell as login button. Use a simple button on login view. On that button's IBAction you can validate user input.

Comment: Okay, I tried this. It seems that the button's target action is still executed before the `textFieldDidEndEditing:` in which I read the value for the text field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple view with two textfields and one UIButton. After the button is pressed you can just remove the view from superview by `[yourView removeFromSuperview]` . You can receive the data from the yourTextfield.text.

I guess this must do the trick

Comment: I didn't quite understand. I specifically wanted to use table view for this and I don't want the overlay (ie. the popup login dialog) to be dismissed before the delegate says so.